# Simplification of LootTable probability distribution

Tags: c#, optimization, probability

I have created a simple LootTable class for a hobby game that I am working on, and it works perfectly fine. However, I am widely aware of a flaw that is present within the code. When I say flaw, I actually mean: an area of the implementation that could be improved/simplified in order to alleviate processing/computational costs. I will try to explain this as best as I can, and before I do, here is the code for my LootTable class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using DreamforceFramework.Framework.Game.Logic.Structs;
using DreamforceFramework.Framework.Probability;

namespace DreamforceFramework.Framework.Game.Probability
{
    public class LootTable
    {
        public string Name;
        private readonly List<string> _lootTable;
        private readonly Dictionary<string, int> _cachedLoot;
        private bool _isRebuildRequired;

        public LootTable()
        {
            _cachedLoot = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            _lootTable = new List<string>();
        }

        public LootTable(string name)
        {
            this.Name = name;
            _cachedLoot = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            _lootTable = new List<string>();
        }

        public void Add(string name, int probability)
        {
            this._cachedLoot.Add(name, probability);
            _isRebuildRequired = true;
        }

        public bool Contains(string name)
        {
            return _cachedLoot.ContainsKey(name);
        }

        public void Add(LootTableItem item)
        {
            this._cachedLoot.Add(item.Name, item.Rarity);
            _isRebuildRequired = true;
        }

        public void Add(List<LootTableItem> items)
        {
            foreach (LootTableItem lootTableItem in items)
            {
                this._cachedLoot.Add(lootTableItem.Name, lootTableItem.Rarity);
            }
            _isRebuildRequired = true;
        }

        public void Remove(string name)
        {
            this._cachedLoot.Remove(name);
            _isRebuildRequired = true;
        }

        public double ComputeProbability(string name)
        {
            double total = _cachedLoot.Values.Sum(n => n);
            double percent = _cachedLoot[name] / total;
            return Math.Round(percent * 100, 2);
        }

        public void Edit(string name, int newProbability)
        {
            this._cachedLoot[name] = newProbability;
            _isRebuildRequired = true;
        }

        public void Clear()
        {
            this._cachedLoot.Clear();
            this._isRebuildRequired = true;
        }

        private void Rebuild()
        {
            _lootTable.Clear();
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> pair in _cachedLoot)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < pair.Value; i++)
                {
                    _lootTable.Add(pair.Key);
                }
            }
            _isRebuildRequired = false;
        }

        public string Next()
        {
            if (_isRebuildRequired)
            {
                this.Rebuild();
            }
            return _lootTable[DreamforceRandom.NextInteger(_lootTable.Count)];
        }

        public List<string> Next(int quantity)
        {
            List<string> returnList = new List<string>();
            if (_isRebuildRequired)
            {
                this.Rebuild();
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < quantity; i++)
            {
                returnList.Add(_lootTable[DreamforceRandom.NextInteger(_lootTable.Count)]);
            }
            return returnList;
        }
    }
}
```

And also the LootTableItem struct:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DreamforceFramework.Framework.Game.Logic.Structs
{
    public struct LootTableItem
    {
        public string Name;
        public int Rarity;
        public LootTableItem(string name, int rarity)
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.Rarity = rarity;
        }
    }
}
```

For those of you who look through the code above, you will see the inefficient area that I am talking about. To generate the internal loot table I create a list of strings, which is equal to the rarity of the item. So say that I put a "Rusty Sword" into the loot table with a rarity of 20. That means that when the loot table is rebuilt, it will add 20 "Rusty Sword" strings to the table. Not a big deal right? But now lets say that I am adding two objects. I add "Ruby" with a value of 100 and an "Emerald" with a value of 100 to the loot table. Well, that means that I will be creating 200 strings in the loot table, which is terribly stupid when it could just be simplified down to adding 1 Ruby string and 1 Emerald string. This would achieve the same probability, which is 50/50.

So my question is: **How do I simplify the probability of the items being added to the LootTable, so that it auto-optimizes the data instead of creating one gargantuan list of strings.**

I hope I explained this clearly enough, I am sometimes rather lacking when it comes to written articulation.

EDIT:

Here is a working solution proposed by the chosen answer:
http://pastebin.com/4w0B0V6y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution has the optimal **O(1)** time complexity for the retrieve operation (`Next` method), but as you mentioned, it uses a lot of space. As you also mentioned, the space could eventually be optimized by finding and eliminating the greatest common divisor, but that's a complex task and also doesn't work if the item rarities are relatively prime. So I'm going to present you a solution with the optimal **O(N)** space complexity (where **N** is the count of the items in the table) and **O(log2(N))** time complexity for the retrieve operation.

Imagine we have the following items in the table:

```
Name         Rarity  
============ ======  
Rusty Sword      20  
Ruby            100  
Emerald         100
```

We can view it this way:

```
Name         Total Range
============ ===== ========
Rusty Sword     20 [0-19]
Ruby           120 [20-119]
Emerald        220 [120-219]
------------ -----
Total          220
```

The total at the bottom represents the `_lootTable.Count` in your implementation while for the item it is the running sum of the counts you were adding at that point. So having a random number in the range **[0, Total-1]** we need to find the index of the item which range contains that number, which can easily be done using a binary search (therefore in **Log2** time).

Here is how you can do that:

First, replace the `_lootTable` member with the following members

```
private List<string> _lootName = new List<string>();
private List<int> _lootTotal = new List<int>();
private int _total;
```

Then change the `Rebuild` method

```
private void Rebuild()
{
    _lootName.Clear();
    _lootTotal.Clear();
    _total = 0;
    foreach (var item in _cachedLoot)
    {
        _total += item.Value;
        _lootName.Add(item.Key);
        _lootTotal.Add(_total);
    }
    _isRebuildRequired = false;
}
```

Add a helper function to encapsulate the logic and update the `Next` methods accordingly

```
private string NextCore()
{
    Debug.Assert(_cachedLoot.Count > 0 && !_isRebuildRequired); // Preconditions
    int total = DreamforceRandom.NextInteger(_total);
    int index = _lootTotal.BinarySearch(total);
    if (index < 0)
        index = ~index;
    else
        index++;
    return _lootName[index];
}

public string Next()
{
    if (_cachedLoot.Count == 0) return null; // Sanity check
    if (_isRebuildRequired)
    {
        this.Rebuild();
    }
    return NextCore();
}

public List<string> Next(int quantity)
{
    var returnList = new List<string>();
    if (_cachedLoot.Count == 0) return returnList; // Sanity check
    if (_isRebuildRequired)
    {
        this.Rebuild();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < quantity; i++)
    {
        returnList.Add(NextCore());
    }
    return returnList;
}
```

And there you go. Hope that helps.

Comment: Looks great, and well explained.

Comment: Your example code is throwing me a lot of errors. I tried implementing it all today; it seems as though you may have confused a few of your types and member variables, such as in your proposed new suggestion of the Rebuild() method. I am trying to figure out what you intended, now. Help would be appreciated though.

Comment: Eh, never mind. I figured it out. Updating the original post with a working class solution in case anyone stumbles across this thread in the future.